# Google+ signin "Getting Started" project - problems with IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, google-plus

Using the C#/.NET Google+ sign-in quick start project, I'm hitting problems with IIS6.  Here are the steps I followed:

- downloaded the project from Github
- modified the index.html and signin.ashx files to contain my Client ID and Client Secret
- running the project on my machine (using the built in web server for Visual Studio 2010) works fine
- published to Windows 2003 server with IIS6
- added "index.html" as a default document for the web site
- set the web site to use an app pool configured for the 4.0 .NET framework
- attempted to access the page from Chrome

Accessing the site with no page specified on the URL (https://myserver.com/gplussample/) brings up the Google+ signin button.  This works great and I'm taken to the page with my profile photo, circles, etc.

However, when I click the "disconnect" button, nothing happens. Using Chrome DevTools to examine the process, I see this error:

```
POST https://myserver.com/gplussample//disconnect 404 (Not Found)
```

The problem is the `//disconnect` - there's no page name (I believe it should be signin.ashx, as that's what works when I'm running the app on the dev web server with Visual Studio 2010).

I then attempted to access the site with a page name specified:

```
https://myserver.com/gplussample/signin.ashx
```

That results in a blank page and again, looking at the Chrome DevTools, I see a 400 Bad Request error for the .ashx handler.  I searched and searched for solutions for .ashx handlers and "bad request" errors, with no success in this particular case.

Thinking IIS6 was the culprit, I published the site to an IIS7 instance.

With no page name specified on the URL (`http://localhost/gplusoriginal/`), I encountered the same error with the "disconnect" button - no action and a 404 error.

When I changed the URL to `http://localhost/gplusoriginal/signin.ashx`, I received this error:

```
Could not create type 'GPlus_ServerSideFlow.Signin'.
```

Again, back to Google and checking on .ashx handlers and issues with IIS7.  I found a post about the web.config and specifying the handler there, so I tried that.

```
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="GPlus_ServerSideFlow.Signin" path="*.ashx" verb="*"
              type="GPlus_ServerSideFlow.Signin" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Adding this snippet to the web.config resolved the "could not create type" error, but resulted in another 400 Bad Request error.

So, my questions are: What has to be done with II6 or IIS7 to get this sample project working?  Are there additional steps in configuring IIS that need to be completed?  Or something missing from the project code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the sample works is that the RESTful endpoints are intercepted by an ashx handler, `signin.ashx.cs`. The handler can't be directly addressed so routes are setup in `global.ashx.cs` to map endpoints (/, /connect, /disconnect, etc) to that route handler.

As the sample ships, it assumes the built-in web server running on the root port. When moving to IIS, you need to change the path matchers from Equals to **EndsWith** in order to match the virtual directory you are deploying to:

```
        // Redirect base path to signin.
        if (context.Request.Path.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            context.Response.RedirectPermanent("signin.ashx");
        }

        // This is reached when the root document is passed. Return HTML
        // using index.html as a template.
        if (context.Request.Path.EndsWith("/signin.ashx"))
        {
```

Apologies for the delay on this... but hopefully that fixes it! [This fork of the C# starter](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-quickstart-csharp) has the changes in it, tested with IIS, and this update may end up getting merged back into the official sample soon.

Comment: Gus, thanks for the reply. I have to admit, I'm totally new to this type of setup and having a difficult time sorting through how things work.  That being said, I published the site to my IIS7.5 instance and tried to work through a couple of your suggestions. In the global.asax, there are no specific endpoints registered - from what I understand it looks like the RegisterRoutes method takes all incoming URLs and forces them through Signin.ashx.  Then, in Signin.ashx, the various endpoints are parsed (disconnect, connect, etc). Also, web.config doesn't specify a default document.

Comment: BTW, just doing https://myserver.com/gplussample/ works - I see the red "Sign in" button - clicking that then takes me to the page with my circles, profile photo, etc. It's just once I'm there, the buttons/endpoints break down.

Comment: You're seeing the sign-in button within the template :)  Check my answer and let me know if this helps!

Comment: After a big more digging, I found a couple things in the web.config I needed to add for IIS to route the handler appropriately, but the biggest issue was the line of code in your answer.  I was publishing the site to a server under a directory, so this bit was never actually executed - yes, it was just displaying the template. Once I accounted for that it worked fine. Thanks for the pointers and sorry for a dumb question! I appreciate you help on this one.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the heads up for issues when deploying to IIS!